# How to retrieve all columns from table1 and matching columns from table2(Left outer join) using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I have to retrieve all the columns from table1 and matching columns from table2. I have a stored procedure as :

```
alter  Procedure [dbo].[usp_Property]
@UserId bigint =null
As
Begin
select P.PID, P.PropertyName, P.SBUArea, P.ListedOn, 
       P.Availability, P.Price,   F.UserID, F.PID as FavProjId  
       from dbo.Property P left outer join dbo.Favorite F
       on (F.PID=P.PID And F.UserID=@UserId)
```

I want to get Linq query for the same. So far I tried with something like

```
//User Id comes from session..
//var userId
var result=(from p in Properties
                   join f in Favorites
                   on p.PID equals f.PID into r
                   from r1 in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where r1.UserID==userId
                   select new
                   {
                     p.PID,
                      p.PropertyName,                       
                      p.SBUArea, p.ListedOn,
                      r1.UserId
                   });
```

Can anyone please correct me. I want to use left outer join or any other alternate thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I beautify your SP's code, I get this:

```
DECLARE @UserId int 
SET @UserId = 12435 

SELECT 
     P.PID
    ,P.PropertyName
    ,P.SBUArea
    ,P.ListedOn 
    ,P.Availability
    ,P.Price
    ,F.UserID
    ,F.PID AS FavProjId  
FROM Property AS P 
LEFT JOIN Favorite AS F
    ON (F.PID=P.PID AND F.UserID = @UserId)
```

Now I wonder if you need that UserId in the WHERE clause of the SQL, or really in the join.

But anyway, here the LINQ-equivalent of exactly that SQL:

```
System.Int64 __UserId = 12435;

var query = (
    from P in Repo.Property
    from F in Repo.Favorite
         .Where(fav=> fav.PID == P.PID && fav.UserID == __UserId)
         .DefaultIfEmpty() // <== makes join left join
    select new
    {
         PID = P.PID
        ,PropertyName = P.PropertyName
        ,SBUArea = P.SBUArea
        ,ListenOn = P.ListedOn 
        ,Availabiity = P.Availability
        ,Price = P.Price
        ,UserId = F.UserID
        ,FavProjId = F.PID 
    }

);

var data = (query).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you plz tell me why not Join keyword. If not then can you please tell me the reason. Thanks

Comment: @User: Because join gets translated to inner join. You have a left join in the SQL you say you want.  The basic problem is, in LINQ you can't specify, left/right/inner on the join keyword. So it always does inner join. But you can still do joins a little bit like in SQL-92, where there are no left/right/inner join keywords, too. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Table-Joins/PerformingLeftOuterJoinsUsingSQL92.htm

Comment: From the example there: SELECT e.ename, j.jobtitle FROM employee e, job j WHERE e.empno = j.empno (+); The (+) is the equivalent of the  DefaultIfEmpty.

Comment: you mean DefaultIfEmpty() is a join(outer join) itself  in the above case.

Comment: @User: I mean the "DefaultIfEmpty" is the equivalent of the "LEFT" modifier before the JOIN-keyword. JOIN alone is just short for "INNER JOIN", if nothing is specified. A left join is always an outer join. A "left inner join" (you get syntax error in SQL) would just be the same as an inner join. The outer is optional, and the only reason it is allowed there is for SQL-92-syntax backwards compatibility. Grammar: <join_type> ::= 
    [ { INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [ OUTER ] } } [ <join_hint> ] ]
    JOIN

Comment: I appreciate your patience and time. Thanks a lot for a wonderful explanation with an answer by just seeing a comment, you came forward to help out. Your response is highly appreciated. +1 .

Answer (score 0):

If you will put the where clause after `join`  you may get null reference exception because `DefaultIfEmpty` returns default value for non matching rows. You can filter the records before joining itself like this:-

```
var result=(from p in Properties
            join f in Favorites.Where(x => x.UserID == userId)
            on p.PID equals f.PID into r
            from r1 in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                p.PID,
                p.PropertyName,                       
                p.SBUArea, 
                p.ListedOn,
                r1.UserId
            });
```

Please note you need to access properties of `Favorites` using `r1`.

**Update:**

As far as I have understood you need all records from `Property` table and only matching rows from `Favorite` table. But you have a filter on your Favorite table so the ultimate data source will differ. Let me make my point clear by this example:-

Suppose you have following data in `Property` table:-

```
PID    PropertyName    Availability    Price
 1          aaa            true         20
 2          bbb            false        10
 3          ccc            true         50
 4          ddd            false        80
 5          eee            true         55
 6          fff            false        70
```

and `Favorite` table like this:-

```
FID    PID    UserId
 1      4      1001
 2      2      1005
 3      5      1007
```

And let's say you want all records for UserId `1005`, then the result should contain all the property Id's from 1 till 6 even if UserId 1005 doesn't match for property Id's 4 & 2 right? So the query above is as per this understanding. Check this [**Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MyBUkE) with same example and output.

Comment: @User - That must be happening because of `userId`  filter otherwise it will return records from both tables.

Comment: as I have a sql query in my question which works fine. My intention is to pass userId and get all records from the Property table and matching records from Favourites based on userId.

Comment: @User - You sure you are fetching  `r1.UserID` & `r1.PID` in your anonymous type?

Comment: did that as well it is not giving required result.

Comment: @User - Check my update and let me know as per my example what output you are expecting. For simplicity I have done this with objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous objects in your selection

```
var result = from t in table1
             join x in table2
             on t.id equals x.id
             select new { id = t.id, col1 = t.col1, col2 = x.col2 }
```

Comment: Question states any alternatives, surely the result is more important than the join used to obtain it.